# PDFlib 7 & 8 changes?

Tags: pdflib

I've been trying to find a list of changes in PDFlib 7 & 8, but all I can find is references to "please see the documentation for details". For example, the "change log" link here:

http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/

Includes bugs fixed since pdflib8 came out, but not the actual changes made in the 8.0 release. Where can I find a list of the major changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found these:

http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/whats-new-in-pdflib-8/

http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/features/PDFlib_7_whatisnew.pdf